# Packaging Python applications with plugins: How to allow user-defined libraries?

Tags: python, plugins, packaging

I have a Python application that allows the user to write their own script/plugin. The application loads the script and runs a function defined in the script.

My question:

- How to allow users to include their own libraries, for example, wheel files or from PyPi.
- (Maybe easier?) If the previous option is too complex, how to bundle a set of libraries with the app?

My first attempt is to use PyInstaller to package the app.
However, it does not include libraries that are not directly used by the application.

Comment: On which kind of client do you want to package your application (web server, windows laptops, mac ...)

Comment: The target is a Linux/Windows desktop app.